# IOS html5 file input video compression 480x360

Tags: html, ios, video, input, upload

I'm trying to create a form with in HTML5 that allow people to push a video to present themselve.
I use the html tag input.

```
<input  name="file" type="file" accept="video/*" capture />
```

In ios, there is a precompression drop the quality from 1920x1080 to 480x360.
Is there any way to cancel that compression and keep the original file instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: No, there is no solution other that going on building a mobile app.